# Autolayout for UITextview inside custom UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a UITextView inside a custom UITextviewCell. I want the cell to grow in size according to the content of UITextview. I have pinned top, bottom, right, left of textview to the content view of cell. When I pre-populate textview with text, it is working fine as expected. Its not working when I enter text with keyboard. Inside my custom cell.

```
UITextView * textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
[textView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[textView setDelegate:self];
[self.contentView addSubview:textView];

NSLayoutConstraint *xConstrain = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *yConstrain = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstrain = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstrain = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

[self.contentView addConstraint:xConstrain];
[self.contentView addConstraint:yConstrain];
[self.contentView addConstraint:rightConstrain];
[self.contentView addConstraint:bottomConstrain];
```

In my tableview controller added following line

```
-(void)viewdidload
 {
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0f ;
 }
```

Comment: If it's working fine, what is your question?

Comment: Its only working when i do settext: with textView but not working when I enter text with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple thing you can do here, one that comes to mind:

• As you are entering text, keep track of the height of the `UITextView`, as in keep an 'old height' variable and a 'new height' variable. To get the 'new height' you could use the `sizeThatFits` method of the `UITextView` with height set to for example 1000 (large enough that it won't constrain your result).

• The moment the new height is different than the old height, either smaller or larger, you reload the cell that houses the `UITextView` you are working on. You can event set the `[cell setNeedsLayout]`, followed by `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` to make sure it resizes.

I'd imagine this should work, please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Do you suggest to use sizeThatFits: method ?

Comment: But I want to use contrains to achieve this. I don't prefer to use setFrame.

Comment: Well, the constraints will only do their job I'd think, the moment you reload the cell. Basically forcing it to 'redo' the calculations with the new text you entered. The reason I'd encourage you to keep track of the 'old' and 'new' height, is to not constantly have to call reload but only when needed.

Comment: Tried [self layoutIfNeeded] and  [self setNeedsDisplay] during -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView but no outcome.

Comment: Did you actually reload the tableview after the text changed as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109586/discussion-between-jaffer-sheriff-and-trdavidson).